# Where find proof of such theorem about uniform convergence of differences

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Where to find a proof of theorem which says that:
if a funcion $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is bounded on a set of positive Lebesgue measure or on the set of second category with Baire property and
$$
\frac{\Delta_h^nf(x)}{h^n} \rightrightarrows g(x) \textrm{ as } h \rightarrow 0
$$
on every compact interval $[c,d]$, to a bounded function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb R$, then $f$ is of class $C^n$ and $g^{(n)}=f$.

Comment: What does that two-arrow symbol mean?

Comment: This means that the expression on the l.h.s. tend uniformly as $h \rightarrow 0$ on $[c,d]$ to the function $g|_{[c,d]}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MR1245559 (94k:26024)
Frölicher, Alfred(CH-GENV-SM); Kriegl, Andreas(A-WIEN)
Differentiable extensions of functions. (English summary) 
Differential Geom. Appl. 3 (1993), no. 1, 71–90.

The review:
A condition is given for functions defined on an arbitrary subset of the real line with values in a Fréchet space (or even in a space of more general type) to admit a smooth extension. This condition is that the difference quotients of the corresponding orders are to be locally bounded. The results are obtained for $C^\infty$-extensions as well as for finite order extensions with locally Lipschitz derivatives. In the last case a continuous linear extension operator is constructed.